# Swift Webview Error - Audio presentation output context not supported by FigEndpointPicker

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, uiwebview, sift

I have an issues with my swift application. I'm using UIWebview and I been getting the following error:

> [AVFigEndpointPickerOutputContextImpl sharedAudioPresentationOutputContext]: Audio presentation output context not supported by FigEndpointPicker

and Thread eroor

> Thread 4: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Here is my ViewController.swift code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent" : "Chrome Safari"])
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = URL(string:"http://example.com/")
        let urlReq = URLRequest(url:url!)

        webView.loadRequest(urlReq)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Coincidentally, I just ran into this same error, and found this post 35 minutes after it had been asked. I can't find any other references to it. I tried recreating your app, and it ran fine, using Xcode 9.  However, I just noticed that, while I get the same error when I try to run my app in Xcode 9 Beta 3 (it runs fine in Xcode 8) using the simulator, it runs normal if I build it to my device. So I'm guessing it's a simulator issue? I don't know. Still working on it.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue with my simulator on Xcode 9 beta 3.
The error detail here 

`[AVFigEndpointPickerOutputContextImpl sharedAudioPresentationOutputContext]: Audio presentation output context not supported by FigEndpointPicker`

The bug did not occur on the older version of Xcode. I will report this issue to Apple through Bug Reporter.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. I was running xCode 9 Beta with iOS 11.0 Beta. So basically I was set up to fail from the beginning.

I reinstalled my xCode to version 8 and I'm using iOS 10, and it works.